# how to set a default value and populate in drop down select box when page loads in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

on document ready, I have given like below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dropID').val(10);
});
```

But whenever page loads, the value is not binded in that select box. Can any one suggest?

Comment: Please add more code, such `html` and a working snippet. But what I get from your question, you need to use `prop` `selected`

Comment: @Pedram setting the value in a standard <select> will select it. We do need to see the HTML to see what Anitha means

Comment: Please return to your questions and interact with people trying to help you

Answer (score 2):

Setting the value in a standard `<select>` will select it.

If your select code does not look like this, then that is the issue.
Assuming you load jQuery and the IDs are correct

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dropID").val(10)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropID">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="10">Ten</option>
  <option value="20">Twenty</option>
  <option value="30">Thirty</option>
</select>
```